# Can I host WSO2 CEP on Bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud, wso2-cep

I want to run my WSO2 CEP on IBM Bluemix. Is it possible to host it as a Liberty application or any other option is available there ?

Answer (score 2):

WSO2 CEP is a Java Web application including Tomcat as application server, so you may have to build it from source and push the war on Bluemix to try it working on liberty application server. Anyway between WSO2 CEP prerequisites there is Java Oracle jdk, and Bluemix is running on IBM jdk, so you could have some other problems.

So maybe it could be better to run it on a (group of) Bluemix Container: these are based on Docker containers, so you could create a custom docker image from the (really) several images available, and then you can push it to a Bluemix container on cloud.
Bluemix/Docker containers are fully portable so you can very easily create your one and take it everywhere and also make it scaling very simply on Bluemix cloud environment.
You can start from here
https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_index.html
https://docs.docker.com/docker/userguide/

Comment: Thank you for this information. I will go with the containers to do it.